# Getting Segmentation Fault in LinkedList

Tags: c++

I m getting Segmentation fault in this code but i don't see any reason why
I m checking if head is NULL then it will be intitialized to temp.

```
void insertFirst(int id,char *name){
    struct Student *temp;
    temp->id=id;
    strcpy(temp->name,name);
    temp->next=NULL;
    temp->prev=NULL;
    if(head==NULL){
        head=temp;
    } else{
        temp->next=head;
        head->prev=temp;
        head=temp;
    }
}
void append(int id, char *name){
    struct Student* temp;
    temp->id=id;
    strcpy(temp->name,name);
    temp->next=NULL;
    temp->prev=NULL;
    if(head==NULL){
        head=temp;
    } else{
        while(head->next!=NULL){
            head=head->next;
        }
        head->next=temp;
        temp->prev=head;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. Also please take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: There are also many other problems with your code. Like if `Student::name` is a pointer and not an array? Like you modifying `head` in the loop in the `append` function? Like you not making `temp` actually point anywhere!

Comment: Proper indentation will go a long way towards making your code readable and debuggable.

Comment: This really looks more like C code than C++ (for starters you don't need to write `struct Student` in C++, just `Student` is enough)

Comment: So your code is full of *undefined behavior* (as your `temp` pointer doesn't point to anything valid) - it might be time to read [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're many problems with this code.

## **Just a working example**

[Complete example](http://ideone.com/PFTNHK)

## **Errors with explanations**

### Assumptions

So far we've no complete problem definition, so I've made several assumtions about your code.

**`Student` definition**

```
struct Student {
  int id;
  char* name;
  Student* next;
  Student* prev;
};
```

**`head` is global variable**

### Fatal errors

**Uninitialized pointers**

Pointer is just a integer of some sort. So when you write:

```
struct Student* temp;
```

You just create integer value without initialization.
It's better to always initialize variables properly, for instance with `NULL` value:

```
struct Student* temp = NULL;
```

**Struct instantiation**

Following code doesn't create intsance of `Student`

```
struct Student* temp;
```

Rather, it just creates a pointer, as shown above.
To actually instantiate `Student` you've to write something like this:

```
struct Student* temp = NULL;
temp = new Student;
```

or shorlty:

```
struct Student* temp = new Student;
```

Here new instance of `Student` will be created.

**Copy string using unitialized pointer**

This problem is similar to first one.
After instantiation of `Student`, `Student::name` points nowhere(actually it points somewhere in memory).
Before copy a `name` you have to allocate memory for that copy & points `Student::name` there. To do this we've to:

- Get amout of memory to be allocated(count of chars in that case).

  ```
  size_t chars_count = strlen(name);
  ```
- Allocate required memory.

  ```
  char* pointer_to_string = new char[chars_count];
  ```
- Assign pointer value to `Struct::name`.

  ```
  temp->name = pointer_to_string;
  ```

or shortly:

```
temp->name = new char[strlen(name)];
```

**Moving head in append function**

`head` is global variable  that have to point to the beginning of the students list.
But in `append` function, this code:

```
while(head->next != NULL) {
  head = head->next;
}
```

will reassign `head` on every iteration. So after first loop execution `head` will point to the last list entry.
To avoid this we've to use additional variable, points to current element.

```
struct Student* pCurrent = head;
while(pCurrent->next != NULL) {
  pCurrent = pCurrent->next;
}
```

Following code will be changed relatively:

```
pCurrent->next=temp;
temp->prev=pCurrent;
```

*P.S. this is not the complete list of errors in this code, but enought to make it work.*

### Recomendations

As addition few styles recomendations from my side.
Complete code example created according theme.

**Code duplication.**
Each function in this sample creates new `Student` instance, using exactly same code.
To avoid this we've to add new function:

```
Student* createStudent(const int id, const char* name, Student* pNext, 
                       Student* pPrev) {
  struct Student* pStudent = new Student;
  pStudent->id = id;
  pStudent->name = new char[strlen(name)];
  strcpy(pStudent->name, name);
  temp->next = pNext;
  temp->prev = pPrev;
  return pStudent;
}
```

**Use const whenever possible.**

Signatures of both functions contains:

```
functionName(int id, char* name)
```

But most likely you wont change provided id or name so replace it with:

```
functionName(const int id, const char* name)
```

**Pass head as an argument.**

We've to avoid usage of global variables to have more control.